# Microsoft .NET Compiler Copyright?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, codedom

I developed a small app which can create `.exe` files using codedom (I think it is [csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)).

It seems that the compiler is included in the .NET framework and not only exclusively in Visual Studio.

Am I allowed to let my software customers create their own exes with my application which uses the .net compiler?

I wont distribute the compiler in my application, it is included in the .net redistributable.

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly become an issue, since you are not distributing a single byte of Microsoft's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Am I allowed to let my software customers create their own exes with my application which uses the .net compiler?"**

Yes. The Express Edition of Visual Studio is free with all the tools (such as .Net, csc.exe & etc):

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express

> Visual C# 2010 Express is part of the Visual Studio 2010 Express
>   family, a free set of tools that Windows developers at any level can
>   use to create custom applications using basic and expert settings.